# How do I test Groovy by Junit5?

Tags: gradle, groovy, junit5

I have Groovy class

```
package com.steinko.groovy;
class Student { 
    String name;
    int ID;

    Student(name,ID){ 
        this.name = name;
        this.ID = ID;

     } 

   String Display() {
      return name +ID;
   }  
}
```

and a Junit 5 test

```
package com.steinko.groovy;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals​;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;



class StudenTest {

    @Test
    void testDisplay() {
      def stud = new Student('Joe', 1)
      def expected = 'Joe1'
      assertEquals(stud.Display(), expected)
   }

 }
```

and I have a Gradle build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'


test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

repositories {
     jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    implementation localGroovy()

    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.5.0")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.5.0")
}
```

when I execute gradle build I get follwing message

```
com.steinko.groovy.StudenTest > testDisplay() FAILED
   groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: >com.steinko.groovy.StudenTest.assertEquals() is applicable for >argument types: (String, String) values: [Joe1, Joe1]
      at >org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:72)
      at >org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:80)
      at >org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:51)
      at >org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:156)
      at >org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:176)
      at >com.steinko.groovy.StudenTest.testDisplay(StudentTest.groovy:14)
```

The test result

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.steinko.groovy.StudenTest.assertEquals() is applicable for argument types: (String, String) values: [Joe1, Joe1]
    at >org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:72)
    at >org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:80)
    at >org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:51)
    at >org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:156)
    at >org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:176)
    at com.steinko.groovy.StudenTest.testDisplay(StudentTest.groovy:14)
```

How do I fix the error?

Comment: Paste the output of `./gradlew -version`. I couldn't reproduce your issue using Gradle 5.5 and 4.6+. The error would make sense if your test was missing the static import of `Assertions.assertEquals`, but it's there in place.

Comment: ------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 5.5
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2019-06-28 17:36:05 UTC
Revision:     83820928f3ada1a3a1dbd9a6c0d47eb3f199378f

Kotlin:       1.3.31
Groovy:       2.5.4
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.14 compiled on March 12 2019
JVM:          12.0.1 (Oracle Corporation 12.0.1+12)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.14.5 x86_64

Answer (score 0):

Using methods from `org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions` is rarely necessary in Groovy since Groovy‘s built-in `assert` command is very powerful.

Just try

```
assert stud.Display() == expected
```

and see how good the failure reporting is.